# FirstOrDefault not taking argument

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq

I put reading barcode in separate method which reads the barcode and put it in a textbox named barcode. and created a button that will load data coresponding to that barcode , but facing problem

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var str = @"<Books xmlns=""""> <book Barcode=""780672318863""><Serial>11</Serial> 
                           <name>abc</name> <detail>Fantasy</detail></book>
                           <book Barcode=""780672318864""><Serial>12</Serial>
                           <name>abc</name><detail>Fantasy1</detail></book></Books>";
    var strBarcode = barcode.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(strBarCode);
    XDocument docX = XDocument.Parse(str);
    var s = docX.Descendants("book").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Barcode").Value == strBarcode);
    spnl.DataContext = s; 
}
```

now Messagebox says strBarCode has correct value  but it is not showing up in program and 
s value is coming out to be null
on other hand if i put directly "780672318863" in place of strBarcode  it is showing value correctly
can anyone tell me where i am going wrong ?

Comment: Your XML doesn't contain *any* elements called "lense" so there's no way this code is going to work at the moment. It would really help if you could post a short but *complete* example (ideally as a console app) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet - But it does have a `<book Barcode="..">` . The OP did an incomplete obfuscation of the domain details.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, but goodness knows what else was changed at the same time. Or maybe it wasn't an obfuscation - maybe it was actually wrong in his code, and he made some other change when he hard-coded the bar code. It's impossible to tell for sure - but we *can* know that the code as written will never find a `lense` element. This is where a short but complete program demonstrating the problem is so important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reproducable.

I ran your code with `docX.Descendants("book")...` and it produces the correct element.

You could try

```
  string  strBarcode = barcode.Text.Trim();
```

but for the rest you will just have to look around in the debugger.

Comment: I am new to WPF but could you tell me what does Trim do

Comment: Trim() has nothing to do with WPF. It's a simple string method that removes leading and trailing spaces (whitespace).